# Different linkage for extern "C" vs. extern "C" { } in C++

Tags: c++

I realize that, at first sight, my question *might seem* an obvious duplicate of one of the many questions here related with the `extern` keyword, but I was unable to find **any answer** talking about the difference between extern "C" and extern "C" { }. On the contrary, I've found several people stating that the two constructs are equivalent, as I believe it is reasonable to expect. Unfortunately, empirical evidence shows that they really **are not** equivalent.

Here is an example:

```
extern "C" { const int my_var1 = 21; }
extern "C" const int my_var2 = 42;
const int my_var3 = 121;

int main() { }
```

After compiling it with gcc 7, with `g++ externC.cpp`, I see a remarkable difference:

```
$ readelf -s ./a.out | grep my_var
    34: 0000000000000694     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 _ZL7my_var1
    35: 000000000000069c     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   15 _ZL7my_var3
    59: 0000000000000698     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 my_var2
```

`my_var1` and `my_var3` both have *local* binding and a C++ mangled name, while `my_var2` has *global* binding and actual C linkage. So, it looks like the `extern "C" { }` has been completely ignored, while the similar `extern "C"` **without** `{}` did have effect. That is **super weird** to me.

Things get even more interesting if I remove the `const` and just try to read the variables:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" { int my_var1; }
extern "C" int my_var2;
int my_var3;

int main() {
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", my_var1, my_var2, my_var3);
}
```

When I try to compile this 2nd program, the linker complains that it has been unable to find a reference for `my_var2`:

```
/tmp/ccfs9cis.o: In function `main':
externC.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `my_var2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And that means that **in this case** two things happened:

1. `extern "C" { int my_var1; }` **instantiated** in the translation
     unit a variable called `my_var1` with C linkage.
2. `extern "C" int my_var2;` **declared** an **extern variable**, where
     with `extern` I mean in the traditional sense
     (like `extern int x;`), but with "C" linkage.

Which, from, my point of view, is inconsistent with the behavior in the 1st case above, using `const`. In other words:

- In the 1st program with const

  - `extern "C"` behaved like I expected `extern "C" {}` to behave
    [change the linkage]
  - `extern "C" {}` instead, did **nothing**
- In the 2nd program, without const:

  - `extern "C" {}` behaved like I originally expected [change the linkage] BUT
  - `extern "C"` behaved like:
    `extern "C" { extern int my_var2; }`
    which is the way to declare an *extern* variable with C
    linkage (and unfortunately in C++ the keyword `extern` has
    been reused).

In conclusion, my question is: can anyone (maybe a compiler expert?) explain the theory behind the reason for `extern "C"` and `extern "C" {}` to behave so differently and in such a inconsistent (at least for me) way ? In mine experience with C++, I realized that once you understand in deep details a given concept, even its tricky and complex corner cases start to look pretty reasonable and consistent. Just, you need to see the whole picture very clearly. I believe that is such a case.

Thanks a lot to everybody, in advance.

---

`Edit[1]`

[At the end it turned that a similar question *did* exist here, just I was unable to find it. Sorry for that.]

Thanks to the answers so far, I understand now the subtle difference between `extern "C" {}` and `extern "C"`, even if I'd still be curious to understand how we (the C++ developers/ISO committee) ended up with such a solution. It's kind-of like making `if (x) foo();` to be behave slightly differently than `if (x) { foo(); }`. Anyway, given this new knowledge, I'd have a few (hopefully) interesting observations to make:

Given that the transformation:
`extern "C" X` => `extern "C" { extern X }` is always correct

It follows that:

- The only way to define (instantiate) a `const` variable with C linkage 
  in the current translation unit is to make it `extern`, even if we want don't want that: the compiler will decide if we're instantiating or just declaring an extern depending on if we initialized the variable with a value: in that case, we're defining, otherwise we're just declaring.
- The same logic (extern + const) applies to regular `const` variables with C++ linkage as well. A `const` variable with C linkage is no different except for the lack of name mangling.
- From the statements above it follows that, since `const` implies *internal* linkage in C++ (but not in C!), the `extern` when used for a `const` does not mean `extern`, but just *less internal* or *more extern than static*.

In other words:

- `const int var = 23;` creates a global variable with internal linkage, like `static int var = 23;` would except for being placed in a read-only segment.
- `extern const int var = 23;` creates a global variable with regular (external) linkage. The `extern` neutralizes the implicit `static`. The result is the same as `int var = 23` except that with `const` it will be placed in a read-only segment.
- `extern const int var;` declares a proper extern variable in a foreign read-only segment.

Comment: `extern "C" BLAH` acts the same as `extern "C" { extern BLAH }`

Comment: What Ben said. Or another way of putting it: `extern "C" { BLAH }` changes only the language linkage of (some of) the declarations inside, but the single declaration version `extern "C" BLAH` both changes the language linkage AND applies all the usual effects of the plain `extern` keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage):

> [`extern "C" { ... }`] Applies the language specification string-literal to all function types, function names with external linkage **and variables with external linkage** declared in declaration-seq.

Since `const int my_var1 = 21;` has internal linkage, wrapping `extern "C" { }` around it has no effect.

Also:

> [`extern "C" ...`] Applies the language specification string-literal to a single declaration or definition.

and

> A declaration directly contained in a language linkage specification is treated as if it contains the extern specifier for the purpose of determining the linkage of the declared name and whether it is a definition.

```
extern "C" int x; // a declaration and not a definition
// The above line is equivalent to extern "C" { extern int x; }

extern "C" { int x; } // a declaration and definition
```

This explains why for `extern "C" const int my_var2 = 42;` the variable has external linkage and an unmangled name. It also explains why you're seeing an undefined reference to `my_var2` in your second code example.

Comment: To quote the same source: "Every function type, every function name with external linkage, and **every variable name with external linkage**, has a property called language linkage. Language linkage encapsulates the set of requirements necessary to link with a module written in another programming language: calling convention, name mangling algorithm, etc."